# Keeping a JList selection of cell that are not focused

Tags: java, swing, jlist, renderer

in my custom renderer every cell is selected gets a light gray background color but as those cell lose the focus the selection made will gone. How can I prevent that?

```
package window;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ListCellRenderer;

import main.Trade;

public class TradeRenderer extends JPanel implements ListCellRenderer<Object>{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus){


        if(isSelected)
            this.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        else
            this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 1, 0,Color.LIGHT_GRAY));

        setEnabled(true);

        return this;
    }

}
```

Comment: How do you select a cell? Just using the keyboard up/down arrow causes the item to be selected. So what exactly are you trying to accomplish. Maybe you should be using a JTable with two columns, one for your data and one with a check box so you can select the row?

Comment: Selection is made with the mouse, every cell is added dynamically to the list. It is only a graphic issue for me.

Comment: A JLIst will work with either the mouse or the keyboard. I still don't know what you mean by selection is made with the mouse. What exactly does the user do? In general only one item can be "selected" at a time. If you want multiple selections then the user needs to hold the "Control" key while clicking the mouse. There is no need for a custom renderer since the JLIst will highlight each "selected" item already.  Your question is still not clear to me